# How to remove dates from a list in Python

Tags: python, regex, nltk

I have a list of tokenized text (list_of_words) that looks something like this:

```
list_of_words = 
['08/20/2014',
 '10:04:27',
 'pm',
 'complet',
 'vendor',
 'per',
 'mfg/recommend',
 '08/20/2014',
 '10:04:27',
 'pm',
 'complet',
 ...]
```

and I'm trying to strip out all the instances of dates and times from this list. I've tried using the .remove() function, to no avail. I've tried passing wildcard characters, such as '../../...." to a list of stopwords I was sorting with, but that didn't work. I finally tried writing the following code:

```
for line in list_of_words:
    if re.search('[0-9]{2}/[09]{2}/[0-9]{4}',line):
        list_of_words.remove(line)
```

but that doesn't work either. How can I strip out everything formatted like a date or time from my list?

Comment: Is there a particular format of data and/or time you want to remove ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Description

```
^(?:(?:[0-9]{2}[:\/,]){2}[0-9]{2,4}|am|pm)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- find strings which look like dates `12/23/2016` and times `12:34:56`
- find strings which also are also `am` or `pm` which are probably part of the preceding time in the source list

## Example

**Live Demo**

- Regex: https://regex101.com/r/yE8oB9/2
- Python: http://codepad.org/X9D3pd7s

**Sample List**

```
08/20/2014
10:04:27
pm
complete
vendor
per
mfg/recommend
08/20/2014
10:04:27
pm
complete
```

**List After Processing**

```
complete
vendor
per
mfg/recommend
complete
```

**Sample Python Script**

```
import re

SourceList = ['08/20/2014',
                 '10:04:27',
                 'pm',
                 'complete',
                 'vendor',
                 'per',
                 'mfg/recommend',
                 '08/20/2014',
                 '10:04:27',
                 'pm', 
                 'complete']

OutputList = filter(
    lambda ThisWord: not re.match('^(?:(?:[0-9]{2}[:\/,]){2}[0-9]{2,4}|am|pm)$', ThisWord),
    SourceList)


for ThisValue in OutputList:
  print ThisValue
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (2 times):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [0-9]{2}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (2 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [:\/,]                   any character of: ':', '\/', ','
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ){2}                     end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{2,4}               any character of: '0' to '9' (between 2
                             and 4 times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    am                       'am'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    pm                       'pm'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This is one of the best explained answers I have come across in a while !

Answer (score 9):

if you want math the time and date string in your list, maybe you can try below regex:

```
[0-9]{2}[\/,:][0-9]{2}[\/,:][0-9]{2,4}
```

[image]

add the python code:

```
import re

list_of_words = [
 '08/20/2014',
 '10:04:27',
 'pm',
 'complet',
 'vendor',
 'per',
 'mfg/recommend',
 '08/20/2014',
 '10:04:27',
 'pm',
 'complet'
]
new_list = [item for item in list_of_words if not re.search(r'[0-9]{2}[\/,:][0-9]{2}[\/,:][0-9]{2,4}', item)]
```

Comment: Your regular expression is great. I have used it in my response.

Comment: @user6188402 \d checks all Unicode digits, while [0-9] is limited to these 10 characters. so [0-9] is more efficient

Comment: It would be cleaner and more efficient to use `re.compile` and then access the compiled expression.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import re

list_of_words = ['08/20/2014',
                 '10:04:27',
                 'pm',
                 'complet',
                 'vendor',
                 'per',
                 'mfg/recommend',
                 '08/20/2014',
                 '10:04:27',
                 'pm', 'complet']

list_of_words = filter(
    lambda x: not re.match('[0-9]{2}[\/,:][0-9]{2}[\/,:][0-9]{2,4}', x),
    list_of_words)
```