# How to remove date chunk from bigger string without regex?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, date

**NOTE - This question might seem similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43316608/remove-timestamp-from-date-string-in-python/43316706) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43316608/remove-timestamp-from-date-string-in-python/43316706) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37473219/how-to-remove-dates-from-a-list-in-python), but none of them exactly solved my problem.**

I want to remove the probable date strings from a string of bigger length containing this date string in between. Like if the input string is `"13th June 2020 is the day to remember"` the output will be `"is the day to remember"`. Now I've already tried these three modules:

1. [parseddatetime](https://pypi.org/project/parsedatetime/)
2. [date-extractor](https://pypi.org/project/date-extractor/)
3. [datefinder](https://pypi.org/project/datefinder/)

Like this:

```
import parsedatetime as pdt
from date_extractor import extract_dates as ed
from datetime import datetime as dt
from datefinder import find_dates as fd
cal = pdt.Calendar()

def check_date_parseddatetime(date_string):
    date_parsed, parse_status = cal.parse(date_string)
    #print(f"check_date_parseddatetime :: date_parsed : {date_parsed}")

def check_date_extractor(date_string, prec_=False):
    try:
        dt_parsed = ed(date_string)
        #print(f"check_date_extractor :: dt_parsed : {dt_parsed}")
    except Exception as e:
        #print(f"check_date_extractor :: error")
        pass

def check_datefinder(date_string, date_extract_result=(False, )):
    datefinder_list = [str(m) for m in fd(date_string)]
    #print(f"check_datefinder :: datefinder_list : {datefinder_list}")
```

Here is a sample output for the string `" 13 jun 19 : Once upon a time"`

given by `parseddatetime`:

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=2020, tm_mon=6, tm_mday=13, tm_hour=16, tm_min=23, tm_sec=48, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=4, tm_isdst=0)
```

given by `date_extractor`:

```
[datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 13, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)]
```

given by `datefinder`:

```
[datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 13, 0, 0)]
```

The problem of using them is they work perfectly fine to parse the exact date from the string, but still they don't return the exact word chunk for which this date is found.

Here are all the test data I'm trying on. The date parsing is working great, but none of them returns any matched string for which this parsed date is extracted:

```
l = ['13 jun 19 : Once upon a time', '13-jun-19', '13JUN19', '13 dec 19', '13-dec-19', '13th june 2019', '13th december 2019', '13-06-19', '13.06.19', '13.6.19', '13.12.19', '13/06/19', '13/12/19', '12 jan 2009', '12 jan, 2009', 'jan 12 2009', 'jan 12, 2009', '12 january 2009', '12 january, 2009', 'january 12 2009', 'january 12, 2009', '01 12 2009', '12-01-2009', '12 - 01 - 2009', '12/01/2009', '12 / 01 / 2009', '12 /01 /2009', '12/ 01/ 2009', '12/ 01 /2009', '12 /01/ 2009', '12 01 2009', '12 1 2009', '13 01 2009', '12 21 2009', '15 1 2009', '2 15 2009', '01-12-2009', '01/12/2009', '12.01.2009', '01.12.2009', '13-Jun-18', '13 Jun 19', '13 Jun, 19', '13, Jun 19', 'bla13 bla 14, Jun 19 sdfhkjn jd 12', '18-Feb-2008', '18 - Feb - 2008', '18 -Feb -2008', '18- Feb- 2008', '18 -Feb- 2008', '18- Feb -2008', '13-Jun-18 , 18-Feb-08', 'june 20', 'Jul 01, 2019', 'Jul 01 2019', 'Aug 5 2019', '21 Jun 2019, 18:00', '6/12/19', '6/18', '29 DEC 19', '29-DEC-19', '29/12/19', '14J1-N19', '12/Jul/2019 12/Aug/2019 MEISHAN BRIDGE 06:00']
```

The *desired output will be vacant string for all cases, except* these three cases where there are extra words except the date:

```
['13 jun 19 : Once upon a time', 'bla13 bla 14, Jun 19 sdfhkjn jd 12', '21 Jun 2019, 18:00', '12/Jul/2019 12/Aug/2019 MEISHAN BRIDGE 06:00']
```

The output for the above three cases should be:

```
[': Once upon a time', 'bla13 bla  sdfhkjn jd 12', ', 18:00', ' MEISHAN BRIDGE 06:00']
```

I've thought of writing regex for each cases, but there are more date test cases to be introduced later (which might be handled using these modules) and thus writing regex for all these many cases to match with the bigger string will be painstakingly hard. How to achieve this without regex? Is there any other module (or any of these three modules) which return the exact match for which we are getting the parsed date and thus can help to remove that part from the bigger string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a new package named [python-sutime](https://github.com/FraBle/python-sutime) [a python wrapper for Stanford NLP's [sutime](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/sutime.shtml) java libraries]. It helps me remove the particular date chunks from strings. It works even if there are multiple dates in single string.

The disadvantage of using this package is additional installation of the java jdk dependencies required. But nevertheless this is kinda perfect for getting the thing done.

Here is the usage example I used :

```
from sutime import SUTime
test_string = "13 jun 19 : Once upon a time"
jar_files = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'jars')
sutime = SUTime(jars=jar_files, mark_time_ranges=True)
sutime_parsed_vals = sutime.parse(test_case)
sutime_parsed_vals = [i for i in sutime_parsed_vals if i['type']=='DATE']
temp_string = deepcopy(test_string)
for parsed_val in sutime_parsed_vals:
    start, end = [parsed_val["start"], parsed_val["end"]]
    temp_string = temp_string[:start] + (end - start)*' ' + temp_string[end:]
output = ' '.join(temp_string.split())
```